# How to logout in Unity3d Fabric Plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, fabric.io

I've install Fabric plugin in my unity project though I don't know how to sign out from it after logging in.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete your fabric settings file and then relaunch the plugin. This should allow you to login with a different account.

Comment: it did not work. I'm using mac and a beep sounds just beeping when CMD-L

Comment: please check out the revised answer above :)